# client.Do errors get status code

Tags: go

When I call `client.Do` method, how would I be notified for errors like 429 response code (aka too many requests). Should I expect to get a response object back with a status code 429 or will I get an error with just the message “too many requests”?

I am seeing the latter and what I need is to be able to get status code for all errors (server/dial/tcp/dns/etc.) and successes and only in some cases I can get the actual code in case of errors. Is there anyway to get all response codes irrespective of the error type - the error message seems to reflect the details but would still like to get the code if possible.

Comment: You don't get an error when you get a response and vice versa. The http status code is something you get with a response, how you interpret that is up to you, but it's not an error condition.

Answer (score 2):

The [`http` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http) covers this very clearly.

Of particular interest are the [documentation for `Do`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do):

> An error is returned if caused by client policy (such as CheckRedirect), or failure to speak HTTP (such as a network connectivity problem). **A non-2xx status code doesn't cause an error.**

(Emphasis added)

And the documentation for the [`Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response) object returned by `Do`:

```
type Response struct {
    Status     string // e.g. "200 OK"
    StatusCode int    // e.g. 200
```